# Running a pedestal fan over UPS

Tags: ups

I'm considering buying a UPS to power a pedestal fan during power outages.
My fan is 60W. I was contemplating buying [this UPS model](http://powerquality.eaton.com/5E650iUSB.aspx?CX=47&GUID=2E4DAA16-FA7E-42E0-92A5-2947C7CB0E84), which is set at 360W.

1. Will this work at all? Or are mechanic motors problematic for UPS for some reason?
2. Could I expect it to work for 360/60 = 6 hours? If not, how long would it be safe to assume it will last for? (I could go for a higher Watt model)
3. On the model page I linked to, there is a battery graph, which shows that the battery wattage over time - Starting at 260W and emptying over ~50 or so minutes. How come the model is rated at 360W if it can't provide 360W for one hour?

Comment: Rent one and try it?  It's true that starting induction motors is 'problematic', though I suspect that the 360W rating would get the squirrels off the starting block.  Expecting 6 hours with such a load is probably optimistic.  360/250 you are confusing power with energy..

Comment: That graph isn't power over time, it's how long the UPS can run at different power loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It should work OK with a fan
2. Read the information in the link: -

[image]

Run-time for delivering 60 watts is 37 minutes.

360 watts is the peak power it can deliver and it doesn't mean it can supply 360 watt-hours.

> *3) How come the model is rated at 360W if it can't provide 360W for
> one hour?*

It can provide a peak load power of 360 watts and not a continuous power of 360 watts for 1 hour. Peak power of 360 watts would be sustained for maybe a minute or less.

Comment: I would estimate the real load vs runtime at 60W to be a bit less than 37 minutes given the simplistic (linear) interpolation used in the graph.